# How to send CAN communication to Stm32f1 MCU?

Tags: c, firmware, hal, stm32f1

I'm trying to CAN transmit on my target board.
My board is not to send CAN message on stm32cubeide but I confirmed that my board send CAN message on mbed.

How can I send CAN message on stm32cubeide??
I intended CAN baudrate 500kbps, sampling point 75% and my apb1 clock is 18Mhz, HSE is 8Mhz, and my crystal is 8Mhz.

Below is `printf()` debug message when my board running and stop.
Always debug message show me the message such as below..

```
<Can Send Success: 1
<Can Send Success: 2
<Can Send Success: 3
<Can Send Success: 4
<Can Send Success: 5
<Can Send Success: 6
<Can Send Success: 7
<Can Send Success: 8
<Can Send Success: 9
<Can Send Success: 10
<Can Send Success: 11
<Can Send Success: 12
<Can Send Success: 13
<Can Send Success: 14
<Can Send Success: 15
<Can Send Success: 16
<Can Send Success: 17
<Can Send Success: 18
<Can Send Success: 19
<Can Send Fail
```

My source code attached below.

```c
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
    /**
      ******************************************************************************
      * @file           : main.c
      * @brief          : Main program body
      ******************************************************************************
      * @attention
      *
      * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
      * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
      *
      * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
      * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
      * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
      *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
      *
      ******************************************************************************
      */
    /* USER CODE END Header */
    /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "main.h"

    /* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

    uint8_t FLAG_RxCplt = 1;
    CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;   // ?��?�� ?��?�� 구조�? �??��
    CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef   TxHeader;
    CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef   RxHeader;
    uint8_t               TxData[8];
    uint32_t              TxMailbox;

    /* USER CODE END Includes */

    /* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

    /* USER CODE END PTD */

    /* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
    /* USER CODE END PD */

    /* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

    /* USER CODE END PM */

    /* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
     CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan;

    TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

    UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
    UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

    /* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

    /* USER CODE END PV */

    /* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
    void SystemClock_Config(void);
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
    static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
    static void MX_CAN_Init(void);
    static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
    static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

    /* USER CODE END PFP */

    /* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
    int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
    {
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)ptr, (uint16_t)len, 100);

      return (len);
    }
    /* USER CODE END 0 */

    /**
      * @brief  The application entry point.
      * @retval int
      */
    int main(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
      int count = 0;
      /* USER CODE END 1 */

      /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

      /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
      HAL_Init();

      /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

      /* USER CODE END Init */

      /* Configure the system clock */
      SystemClock_Config();

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

      /* USER CODE END SysInit */

      /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_USART2_UART_Init();
      MX_CAN_Init();
      MX_TIM2_Init();
      MX_USART3_UART_Init();
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
      HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT (&htim2);

      /* CAN Filter */
      sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
      sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
      sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
      sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
      sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
      sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
      sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;               
      sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
      sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
      sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

      if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        /* Filter configuration Error */
        Error_Handler();
      }
      
      if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
        {
          /* Start Error */
          Error_Handler();
        }
        
        //HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan, )
      /* USER CODE END 2 */

      /* Infinite loop */
      /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
      while (1)
      {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        HAL_Delay(100);
        TxHeader.StdId = 0x7fe;
        //TxHeader.ExtId = 0x1FFFFFFF;
        TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
        TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
        TxHeader.DLC = 8;
        TxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;
        //
        TxData[0] = 1;
        TxData[1] = 2;
        TxData[2] = 3;
        TxData[3] = 4;
        TxData[4] = 5;
        TxData[5] = 6;
        TxData[6] = 7;
        TxData[7] = 8;

        //TxMailbox = HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(&hcan);
        if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
        {
          printf("Can Send Fail\r\n");
            Error_Handler();
        }
        //while(HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(&hcan) != 3) {}
        printf("Can Send Success: %d\r\n", ++count);

      //   if(FLAG_RxCplt)
      //   {
      //     HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,test,1);
      //     FLAG_RxCplt=0;
      //   }

       }
      /* USER CODE END 3 */
    }

    /**
      * @brief System Clock Configuration
      * @retval None
      */
    void SystemClock_Config(void)
    {
      RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
      RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

      /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
      * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
      */
      RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
      RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
      if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }

      /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
      */
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                                  |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
      RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

      if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
    }

    /**
      * @brief CAN Initialization Function
      * @param None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void MX_CAN_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 1 */
      hcan.Instance = CAN1;
      hcan.Init.Prescaler = 9;
      hcan.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
      hcan.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
      hcan.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_2TQ;
      hcan.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
      hcan.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
      hcan.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
      hcan.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
      hcan.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
      hcan.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
      hcan.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
      if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END CAN_Init 2 */

    }

    /**
      * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
      * @param None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

      TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
      TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
      htim2.Instance = TIM2;
      htim2.Init.Prescaler = 36-1;
      htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
      htim2.Init.Period = 1000-1;
      htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
      htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
      if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
      sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */

    }

    /**
      * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
      * @param None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
      huart2.Instance = USART2;
      huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
      huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
      huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
      huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
      huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
      huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
      huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
      if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

    }

    /**
      * @brief USART3 Initialization Function
      * @param None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
    {

      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 0 */

      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 1 */

      /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 1 */
      huart3.Instance = USART3;
      huart3.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
      huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
      huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
      huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
      huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
      huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
      huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
      if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
      /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_Init 2 */

      /* USER CODE END USART3_Init 2 */

    }

    /**
      * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
      * @param None
      * @retval None
      */
    static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
    {
      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

      /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

      /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, Rsig_Pin|Gsig_Pin|Bsig_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

      /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, RS485_DE_Pin|testled_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

      /*Configure GPIO pins : Rsig_Pin Gsig_Pin Bsig_Pin */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Rsig_Pin|Gsig_Pin|Bsig_Pin;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /*Configure GPIO pin : PB13 */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /*Configure GPIO pin : RS485_DE_Pin */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RS485_DE_Pin;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(RS485_DE_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /*Configure GPIO pin : testled_Pin */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = testled_Pin;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(testled_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /*Configure GPIO pins : PS_SIG1_Pin PS_SIG2_Pin */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PS_SIG1_Pin|PS_SIG2_Pin;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      /* EXTI interrupt init*/
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

    }

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

    /* USER CODE END 4 */

    /**
      * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
      * @retval None
      */
    void Error_Handler(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
      /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
      __disable_irq();
      while (1)
      {
      }
      /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
    }

    #ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
    /**
      * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
      *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
      * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
      * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
      * @retval None
      */
    void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
      /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
         ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
      /* USER CODE END 6 */
    }
    #endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: What results are you getting instead of the expected? What does " my board is not to send CAN message" mean, do you get error frames or nothing at all? What makes you think the problem is the software and not hardware?

Comment: I expected transmit can data of eight message such as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. but I don't received at transmit can data with can analyzer(Kvaser).